# Substituir string mantendo a caixa (maiúscula/minúscula)

Tags: ruby, regex

Qual a melhor forma de substituir um padrão por uma string mantendo a caixa?

Por exemplo, `DAdo` -> `LAdo` ou `dado` -> `lado`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você usar o método `gsub` da string para fazer a substituição usando expressão regular, mas ao invés de passar um segundo parâmetro fixo, use um bloco de código para processar cada trecho encontrado de acordo com as maiúsculas e minúsculas, o que já é um outro desafio.

Fiz uma implementação simples desse processo em duas etapas.

Primeiro, a função abaixo converte os caracteres uma string `alvo` de acordo com a string `padrao`:

```
def samecase(padrao, alvo)
    alvo.split("").zip(padrao.split(""))
        .map { |a, p| p.upcase == p ? a.upcase : a.downcase }
        .join("")
end
```

A primeira linha da função usa a função `split` para quebrar as duas strings em arrays de caracteres. Depois, a função `zip` cria um array de pares. Por exemplo, as strings `bar` e `foo` iriam gerar o array `[[b,f],[a,o],[r,o]].

Então, na segunda linha, a função `map` gera um novo array com base no valor retornado pelo bloco de código. O bloco verifica se o caractere atual `p` da string `padrao` é maiúscula e se for ele retorna o caractere correspondente `a` da string `alvo` em maiúscula, caso contrário ele força minúsculo.

A última linha simplesmente junta os caracteres resultantes numa nova string.

Agora, usando a função descrita acima, podemos fazer uma nova função para realizar a substituição seguindo o padrão:

```
def replace_with_case(str, padrao, novo_valor) 
    str.gsub(/#{padrao}/i) { |matched| samecase(matched, novo_valor) }
end
```

A rotina acima, recebe uma string `str` que será pesquisada procurando pelo valor do parâmetro `padrao` e então substituído pelo `novo_valor` transformado com as mesmas "caixas" do texto encontrado.

#### [Veja o exemplo funcional no Ideone](https://ideone.com/TP4ULi)

Comment: A ideia é essa. Como sou iniciante na linguagem há algumas coisas que ainda preciso estudar para ter uma melhor compreensão do seu código. Obrigado pelo retorno e excelente explicação!